# How to publish in VS2013 with multi .config files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-config

I have a project with three main .config files (web.config, one.config and two.config) with multi sub .config (web.debug.config, web.test.config, one.debug.config, one.test.config, two.debug.config, two.test.config ect.)

I make a Publish in VS2013 where I can choose witch web.XXX.config file I will use and it work fine. But how can a choose the one.XXX.config and two.XXX.config file?

Answer (score 0):

"First of all, you need to have the Visual Studio Web Application build targets installed on your build server. This can be achieved either by installing an express version of Visual Studio or the Visual Studio Shell Redistributable Package.

Then, create an App.config file in your project. I placed in in a folder called "Config", to avoid any automatic behaviour from Visual Studio. Then, create your transform files, App.Debug.config, App.Release.config and whatever you need (I usually don't use those, but rather Test, Prod, Acceptance etc). Now, these will all be placed beside App.config, and not be linked to it as with Web.config transforms. Not to worry, we'll fix that shortly!

Next, unload your project, and edit the .csproj file. First we'll fix the linking of the files. This is done simply by adding a DependentUpon element inside each Item. Let's say you have this:

```
<None Include="Config\App.config" />
<None Include="Config\App.Debug.config" />
```

Simply change it to this:

```
<None Include="Config\App.config" />
<None Include="Config\App.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

Now, let's move on the real trick. In order to make msbuild transform your config file, we need to att a build event. At the end of the file, add

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" <br>   AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <TransformXml Source="Config\App.config"
                Transform="Config\App.$(Configuration).config"
                Destination="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).$(OutputType).config" />
</Target>
```

Source: http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Applying-MSBuild-Config-Transformations-to-any-config-file-without-using-any-Visual-Studio-extensions